# Ssh No route to host

Tags: ssh, networking, scp

I am trying to copy my Corosync key from my desktop to my laptop.

```
sudo scp /etc/corosync/authkey  mm-HP-Elit@192.168.0.10:~
```

What I got is this

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: No route to host
lost connection
```

Both of them use the same router in my house.

From my desktop, I am pinging laptop

```
ping 192.168.0.10
PING 192.168.0.10 (192.168.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.29 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.03 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.10: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.05 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.10 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.039/1.118/1.298/0.110 ms

    4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3004ms
```

Telenet is refused

```
telnet 192.168.0.10 22
Trying 192.168.0.10...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

My desktop IP

```
inet 192.168.0.12/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
```

My laptop IP

```
inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
```

My idea was to open port 22.
Netstat output

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:902             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38183           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55181           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38767         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2224            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8307          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57721           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3340/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3340/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5473            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3340/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37795           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::902                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::48647                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2224                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::39283                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::51607                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::35835                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN      3340/dropbox        
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I tried again to open 22

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

but still I do not see 22 with netstat

```
netstat -tpln | grep 22
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2224            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2224                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

How to resolve this problem?

SOLVED
It was an sshd issue. I purged and installed OpenSSH server.

Comment: Can you ping your desktop from your laptop?

Comment: I can ping it,works OK.

Comment: Your edit says: All ports are filtered. Please check the firewall settings of your laptop.

Comment: Which port should I open?

Comment: Is it one of the hosts via WiFi?

Comment: Yes,the laptop is via Wifi.

Comment: @MikiBelavista, connect both of them to wire network and try again. And as mentioned above also open port 22 on target machine

Comment: Time to live exceed means there are routing loops

Comment: Are they on same local-area-network, or via a router. Beware the thing that your ISP gave you, may not be acting as a router (e.g. if all devices on internal network). What is IP address of each machine? (run `ip addr` on each), where did they get IP address from? (manual, dhcp, other)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I think theyr are on same LAN.I added everything.

Comment: Somewhere in this you have a typo in your question or at the command line...  Both your desktop and laptop have are on a /24 subnet `192.168.0.x` but you are trying to connect to `192.168.2.x`.  Is this a typo in your question or are you actually making this same mistake at the command line?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro being a pedant I'd say that `Time to live exceed` means that a packet has been passed through a router too many times.  This *almost* exclusively is caused by a routing loop.  But only *almost*. :-)

Comment: @PhilipCouling Thanks for noting typo. Please,take a look at my edit. I tried to open 22 port.

Comment: Is `sshd` running? Don't use IPtables. `gufw` can but used for simple firewall configuration.

Comment: I think your initial problem (`No route to host`) has gone away, it now has `Connection refused` (I think that you diagnostics or from many different runs, under different conditions). Is `sshd` running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see SSH port on your netstat result.

Desktop IP: 192.168.0.12

Laptop IP: 192.168.0.10

1. Need to make sure desktop can ping laptop

   ```
   ping 192.168.0.10
   ```
2. If ping succeeds, then telnet to ensure SSH port is available and allowable. 
   (Default SSH port is 22; I don't know whether you changed it on your system.)

   ```
   telnet 192.168.0.10 22
   ```

Telnet OK --> you can run scp command.

Telnet Not OK --> recheck the SSH service running.

How to check SSH service running?

- check systemd
- check iptables (or ufw) allowing SSH port.
- `netstat -tapln | grep 22`

Comment: How to check iptables allowing ssh port?

Comment: check systemd
<systemctl status ssh>

then check iptables running
<systemctl status iptables> 

also
<iptables -L>

if you are using Ubuntu, the firewall is ufw, then
ufw status

Answer (score 2):

Check whether sshd service is running or not. `systemctl status sshd`